# C++ How to append char to previously reversed char?

Tags: c++

Hello I need to make insert/append/concat function. How to add reversed chars to my "main char"? Example output is commented.

Here is my func code and main:

```
void app(char *str2,const char *str1){
    const char *temp=str1;
    char* temp_snd=str2;
    const char*temp_trd=str1;
    char *temp_fth;
    while(*temp_trd){
        temp_trd++;
    }
    while(temp_trd!=str1){
        temp_trd--;
        *temp_fth=*temp_trd;
        temp_fth++;
    }
    *temp_fth='\0';
    while(*temp&&*temp_snd){
        temp++;
        temp_snd++;
    }
    while(temp!=str1&&temp_snd!=temp){
        temp--;
        temp_snd++;
        *temp_snd=*temp;
    }
    strcat(temp_snd, temp_fth);
}
```

and this is my main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char *str1 = "seY ";
    char str2[20] = "Hello";
    cout << str2 << endl;    // Hello
    app(str2, str1);
    cout << str2 << endl;    // Hello Yes 
    app(str2, "llor ");
    cout << str2 << endl;    // Hello Yes Roll
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Hello
Hello Yes
Hello  roll
```

I know that my function is no perfect made but be compassionate. Please.

Comment: Are you asking us to finish your program for you? Or what?

Comment: Don't hate. I'm asking you for some tips. I don't have an idea what i'm doing wrong. I'm not fluent in C++

Comment: It's not "hate"; how absurd! This is not a "tips" website. It is a Q&A repository. Please read the "How to Ask" section of the help centre. You may try asking for tips in a chat room?

Comment: Can you please explain your question a little more clearly? 
Try speaking this out loud - " How to add reversed chars to my "main char" " . Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have two chars, first is "Hello" 2nd is "seY " i need to reverse 2nd and add it to first, if i invoke my function again i.e with "llor " i need to add it to first and my output should be "Hello Yes roll". There is my question How?! What's wrong with my function?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
void add (char x[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n; // Length of string
    char*y=new char[n];
    cin >> y;
    reverse(y, y+strlen(y));
    strcat(x, " ");
    strcat(x, y);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n; // Length of base string 
    char *x=new char[n];
    cin >> x;
    add(x);
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: I need to make it on chars

Comment: Sorry for that but my function should have 2 arguments
"void app(char *str2,const char *str1)"

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to do your homework for you. I think I did more than enough by giving you the code tailored exactly according to your instructions. What is posted in the answer is self explanatory. Please use your own brain and do the rest yourself.